# Company hub app not working in Windows MDM

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm, windows-phone-8-emulator

We have successfully done enrolment in Windows MDM. Now we are independently developing hub app means we are not passing hub app during enrolment.We have made hub app and testing it in emulator/device whether it can correctly install other packges.

When I run hub app in debug mode in emulator/device, I can see 2 apps in list.I click on any of the apps,installation starts and always failed.Publisher Id of hub app and 2 apps inside list is same.Have a look at following snaps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Company hub app is working fine now.
See I have 1 app(say hub app) within which I install another app(say app2).App2 getting installed properly. Publisher Ids of both apps is same.but whenever I am calling InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher(); method,its giving list which contains hub app only and not app2.

Ideally both apps should be in the list.Where can I go wrong?